# Утечка памяти при работе с HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#

Проблема в следующем, есть программа, которая должна многопоточно перебирать списки сайтов, запросы реализованы следующим образом:

```
static string Get(string adr)
{
    string content = "";
    HttpWebResponse response=null;
    Stream stream=null;
    StreamReader reader=null;

    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://"+adr);
        //WebProxy prx = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0";
        req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        req.Proxy = null;
        req.KeepAlive = false;
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en;q=0.8");
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        req.Timeout = 10000;
        req.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000;
        req.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 1;
        req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

        using (response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
        using (stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.Default))
        {
            content = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(reader.ReadToEnd());

            response.Close();
            stream.Close();
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
    catch 
    {
        response.Close();
        stream.Close();
        reader.Close();
    }
    return content;
}
```

В потоках просто происходит вызов этой функции и обработка полученного содержимого. Вот несколько скриншотов с утилиты dotMemory:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, переполняется область Heap Generation 2, а, в частности, типами данных Char[] и StringBuilder. Проблема в том, что у меня нет типа данных StringBuilder или Char[] в коде, я использую String и List() . Подозреваю на код внутри класса HttpWebRequest, не знаю просто на что уже другое думать. Просто происходит рост занятой оперативной памяти до зависания приложения. Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: А причём тут Heap Generation 2 к переполнению _стека_?

Comment: `reader.ReadToEnd()`. Хм. А какого размера поток? Может, он реально **очень** большой?

Comment: Я не знаю насчёт dotMemory, а Ants Memory Profiler вполне умеет показать retention graph: кто держит строки, кто держит того, кто держит строки и т. д. Если dotMemory так не может, попробуйте Ants: у него есть бесплатный месяц trial period.

Comment: Изучите множества объектов Char[] и String подробнее. Для этого кликните на ссылке и в открывшейся view выберите [Group by Dominators(Sunburst chart)](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/help/Dominators_Chart.html) или [Group by Similar retention](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/help/Similar_Retention.html).
Сразу станет понятно, кто их наплодил

Answer (score 5):

В коде из вопроса нет ничего подозрительного (кроме трех лишних вызовов Close в catch - они уже продублированы using-ами, а при ошибке в `response.GetResponseStream()` вы получите `NullReferenceException` на `stream.Close()`).

С большой вероятностью проблема, если она есть - не в коде из вопроса, а в коде парсинга.

Судя по скринам, почти вся память у вас занята всего 15-ю StringBuilder-ами. В dotTrace есть поиск GC Roots для объектов - цепочек ссылок, которые предотвращают уход конкретных объектов в мусор. Скорее всего он запускается при клике на ссылк StringBuiler на скриншоте.

Вам стоит просмотреть корни для этих 15-ти StringBuilder-ов и выяснить, действительно ли это мусор (т.е. вы где-то случайно сохранили ссылку на длинную строку и забыли ее занулить) или это реальные данные, с которыми ваше приложение работает. 15 объектов вполне реально просмотреть вручную.